# Function for calculating the mean of an array double[] using accumulate

Tags: c++, arrays, visual-studio-2010, stl, std

It must be the most common function for what everyone has a code snippet somewhere, but I have actually spent no less than 1.5 hour searching for it on SO as well as on other C++ sites and have not found a solution.

I would like to **calculate the mean of a `double array[]` using a function**. I would like to pass the array to the function as a **reference**. There are millions of examples where the mean is calculated in a main() loop, but what I am looking for is a function what I can put in an external file and use it any time later.

So far, here is my latest version, what gives a compile error:

```
double mean_array( double array[] )
{
    int count = sizeof( array ) / sizeof( array[0] );
    double sum = accumulate( array, array + count, 0 );
    return ( double ) sum / count;
}
```

The compile error is:

> error C3861: 'accumulate': identifier not found

Can you tell me how to fix this function? What does that compile error mean?

If I use `std::accumulate` (over the already defined `using namespace std`), then I get the following error:

```
'accumulate' : is not a member of 'std'
'accumulate': identifier not found
```

Why is 'accumulate' not a member of 'std'?

*p.s.: I know I can do 'sum += array[i]' way and not use accumulate, but I would like to understand what is happening here and how can I make my example work.*

Comment: I am not sure, but just wondering, did you add the necessary Include file?

Comment: Be careful: `accumulate( array, array + count, 0.0 );` Note the 0.0 - you are accumulating integers in your code snippet.

Comment: So if I start with 0.0 does it work well? Do I need to pass on the count, or I can calculate it from sizeof?

Comment: You can not use `sizeof(array)` as the size of the array is not known. See @xanatos answer below for a better way in this case.

Comment: By the way its good to use std::accumulate here.  If your array is very large then it can be trivially parellelised with, for_example, __gnu_parallel::accumulate.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Try to add

```
#include <numeric>
```

It will bring in the 'std::accumulate' function you're looking for.

Going further, you're gonna have a problem to find out the number of elements in your array. Indeed, an array cannot be passed to a function in the hope that the function will be able to know the size of the array. It will decay to a pointer. Therefore, your `count` calculation will be wrong. If you want to be able to pass an actual size specified array, you have to use a templated function.

```
template <int N>
double mean_array( double ( & array )[N] )
{
    return std::accumulate( array, array + N, 0.0) / (double)(N);
}
```

Comment: I am not sure if this templated function can be called in an Objective-C method(wrapper). @didier-trosset: Can you please elaborate how the template is helping with the count?
If I have to call the C++ function from Objective-C where I already have the count, would you agree that templating would no longer be required since count be passed as the second argument of this function?

Comment: @KushalAshok Correct. Either you pass a pointer and a count to a non-templated function; or you pass only an array to a templated function (that will guess the count).

Comment: thanks for confirming. I did pass the pointer and count and could not find any memory leaks when running though Instruments

Answer (score 3):

Its not quite the question you asked, but there is an easy bug to make in your code sample.  The initial value in `accumulate` is templated, and in your code its templated to integers.  If you pass it a set of doubles, these will be cast to integers and you will get the wrong answers.  Having made this mistake before, I made myself a quick guarentee as follows:

```
  /** Check that not inputting integer type into accumulate
   *  This is considered an error in this program (where a double was expected
   *  @tparam InputIterator The iterator to accumulate
   *  @tparam T The type to accumulate - will fail if integer.
   *  @param first The first iterator to accumulate from.
   *  @param last the iterator to acculate to,
   *  @param init The initial value
   *  @return The accumulated value as evaluated by std::accumulate.
   */
  template<class InputIterator, class T>
  inline
  T
  accumulate_checked(InputIterator first, InputIterator last, T init )
  {
    return std::accumulate(first,last, init);
  }

  //Not implemented for integers (will not compile if called).
  template<class InputIterator>
  inline
  int
  accumulate_checked(InputIterator first, InputIterator last, int init );
```

Thought I would share it in case it is of interest.

Just for completeness, your function can look like:

```
double mean_array( double *array, size_t count )
{
    double sum = std::accumulate(array,array+count,0.0)
    return sum / count;
}
```

or to be extra careful

```
double mean_array( double *array, size_t count )
{
    double sum = accumulate_checked(array,array+count,0.0)
    return sum / count;
}
```

or better still the templated version from Didier Trosset

Answer (score 2):

To use `std::accumulate` you need to include the appropriate header. Add the following to your source file.

```
#include <numeric>
```

Comment: OK, it seems it is the one I was missing. I have a lot of includes, I missed that one.

Answer (score 0):

```
double mean_array( double *array, size_t count )
{
    double sum = 0.0;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        sum += array[i];
    }

    return sum / count;
}
```

or

```
double mean_array( double *array, size_t count )
{
    double sum = 0.0;
    double *pastLast = array + count;

    while (array < pastLast)
    {
        sum += *array;
        array++;
    }

    return sum / count;
}
```

If you pass an array to a function, you "lose" its size, so you have to pass it as a parameter (it's a little more complex than this... but for now it should be enough)

Comment: But I don't understand, isn't it working with `int count = sizeof( array ) / sizeof( array[0] );` ?

Comment: What part of `If you pass an array to a function, you "lose" its size, so you have to pass it as a parameter` isn't clear? `sizeof(array) is == sizeof(double*)` at that point. The size of the array is lost if you pass it to a function. If you don't trust me, try debugging it.

Comment: @zsero: When you pass an array as a function parameter it decays to a pointer. This is no longer an array type and "loses" the size. Typically, you would also pass the size as a separate parameter like xanatos' examples.

Comment: OK, now it's clear. I didn't know it 'decays' to an pointer. Thanks for the code and the explanation.