# Passing arrays as a reference

Tags: c++, arrays, visual-studio-2010, stl

In C++ how can I pass **an array as a reference** when I don't know the size at compile time? So far, I found out that the only way to make it work is to use something like

```
const double( &numbers ) [size]
```

but it means that I need to **know the size of the array at compile time**, thus I cannot use it in an external function.

My questions are:

1. If I don't pass an array as a `( const double( &numbers ) [length] )`, because for example I don't know its size, **how do I make sure that it doesn't get copied**, but it is **referenced**?
2. If I pass an array like in the above example, `( double array[] )` is it **referenced** or is it **copied**?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In C++, you should use [std::vector](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector).

In C/C++, you can't pass arrays as a copy. Arrays are always passed by reference.

**EDIT**

In C++, *arrays passed by reference* has different meaning. In both C and C++, arrays decay into a pointer to the first element of the array. Please check the comments below.

Comment: *Arrays are always passed by reference* is not quite true, the array decays into a pointer, and that pointer is then passed by value. The difference being that the type changes, outside of the function it can be a proper array ( `T [10]`) while inside the function it will be treated as a pointer (`T*`), with the few differences that entail (result of `sizeof` being the biggest of them)

Comment: arrays passed by reference - this implies that if you modify array content it will be reflected outside the function. that's what i meant.

Comment: In C++ (not C) you can pass arrays by reference, or you can pass a pointer to the first element, the syntax for both are: `void f( int (&x)[10] ); void g( int *p );` and both operations have different semantics. Note that *by-reference* has a precise meaning in C++ that does not mean *can modify the object outside*, or else `void h( int* )` would be *passing an int by reference*. The comment is because I have read that sentence many times, and I have seen people confused because of that. The array is not copied, but it is not passed by reference either, it *decays*, pointer passed by value.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas: edited my answer. i didn't know that in c++ arrays can also be passed by reference. thanks.

Answer (score 10):

The other answers are great, but no one mention using templates to handle this. You should still make your function take a pointer and a size, but templates can fill that automatically for you:

```
void f( double const numbers[], std::size_t length )
{ ... }

template< std::size_t Length >
void f( double const (&numbers)[ Length ] )
{
    return f( numbers, Length );
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I got a really nice answer for my other question here, it is using templates! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7899237/function-for-calculating-the-mean-of-an-array-double-using-accumulate/7899264#7899264

Answer (score 3):

> If I don't pass an array as a ( const double( &numbers ) [length] ),
>   because for example I don't know its size, how do I make sure that it
>   doesn't get copied, but it is referenced?

Yes, it means you're passing an array as reference,

```
void Foo(const double( &numbers ) [length]);
```

Note that the `length` is a constant integer.

> If I pass an array like in the above example, ( double array[] ) is it
>   referenced or is it copied?

No, it is not copied. It means you're passing a pointer to your array which is equivalent to,

```
void Foo(const double *length);
```

Answer (score 2):

A couple things:

1. C++ doesn't allow variable-sized arrays anyway. So all your arrays will need to have known sizes at compile time. So I'm not entirely sure if your initial question is even applicable since you won't be able to make an array with an unknown size in the first place.
2. When you pass an array, it is done by reference. It is not copied.

In any case, you'll probably want to consider using `vector` instead.

**EDIT : See comments.**

```
double average(const double *arr, size_t len){
    //  Compute average
    return accumulate(arr, arr + len, 0) / (double)len;
}

int main(){

    double array[10] = //  Initialize it

    cout << average(array, 10) << endl;

    //  Alternatively: This could probably be made a macro.
    //  But be careful though since the function can still take a pointer instead
    //  of an array.
    cout << average(array, sizeof(array) / sizeof(double)) << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: My array's size is know at compile time, but I cannot hard code it into an external function file. I would like to have a snippet what I can keep in something like `myfunctions.h` and use it for arrays whenever I need to calculate an average.

Comment: In that case, you should pass it as a pointer with a separate size parameter.

Answer (score 2):

In C++, an array's name is just a *constant pointer* to its first element. A *constant pointer* means a pointer that's capable of changing whatever it points to, but it can't be changed to point to something else.

This means that whenever you pass an *array*, you're actually passing a *constant pointer* to that array. In other words, you're already passing it by reference, no need for extra efforts. To be more accurate, what is actually *copied* is that *constant pointer*, so the final (hopefully not-that-confusing) phrasing is that you're passing a *constant pointer* to the array *by value*.

If you don't know your array's size at compile time, just use a (normal) pointer to your data type instead of an explicit array. So whatever is `T my_array[]` (where `T` is a type, like `int`, `double` or even one of your classes) becomes `T* my_array`, and the syntax is exactly the same hereafter... `my_array[i]` will work fine (another syntax also exists, but not as elegant). For initialization, use the `new` operator:

```
T* my_array;

my_array = new T[3];
```

or

```
T* my_array;

my_array = new T[x];
```

where `x` is an integer (not necessarily constant as is the case with normal arrays). This way you can take this `x` from the user at runtime and create your "array" then. Just take care not to forget `delete[] my_array` after you finish using it to avoid memory leaks.

[Final Note] Using such a *dynamically allocated* array is a good choice only when you know exactly how many elements you want... either at compile time or even at runtime. So, for example, if after the user supplies his `x` you'll exactly be using those, that's fine. Otherwise you're facing the danger of overflowing your array (if you need more than `x`) - which usually crashes the application - or just wasting some space. But even if this is the case, you'll implement most of the functions you need for array manipulation yourself. That's why it's preferable to use containers provided by the C++ Standard Library, like `std::vector` (as [Donotalo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/68304/donotalo) mentioned). I just wanted to elaborate on that point more.

Answer (score 0):

Other languages like Java and Python do store the length of arrays at runtime. In C++ arrays, the length of the array is not stored. That means you need to store it manually somewhere.

Whenever you have a fixed size array on your code, the compiler knows the size of the array since it is reading it from the source code itself. But once the code get compiled, that length information is lost. For example:

```
void f1(double array[10]) {...}
```

The compiler won't enforce the size of the array. The following code will silently compile since the array parameter of `f1` us just a pointer to the first element of an array:

```
void h1() {
    double a[10];
    double b[5];

    f1(a); // OK.
    f2(b); // Also OK.
}
```

Since the compiler ignores the static size of the array when passing it to a function, the only way you have to know the size of an arbitrarily sized array passed as a reference is to explicitly state the size:

```
void f2(double array[], size_t array_size) {...}
```

Then you can call that function with any array:

```
void h2() {
    double a[10];
    double b[19];

    f2(a, sizeof(a) / sizeof(a[0]));
    f2(b, sizeof(a) / sizeof(a[0]));
}
```

The parameter `array_size` contains the actual size of the array.

As a note, `sizeof(array)` only works on statically defined arrays. When you pass that array to another functions, the size information is lost.

An array is not the same as a pointer. However, an array of undefined size like the parameter of `f2` is just a pointer to the first `double` element in the sequence:

```
void f3(double array*, size_t array_size) {...}
```

For any practicar purpose, `f2` and `f3` are equivalent.

This is exactly how `std::vector` works. Internally, a vector is a class with two fields: a pointer to the first element, and the number of elements in the vector. This makes things a little simpler when you want to accept an array of any size as a parameter:

```
void g(std::vector& v) {...}
```

Comment: "_This instruct the compiler only to accept as a parameter an array of fixed size 10._" No it doesn't.